# Java library for Fourier transform like in Mathcad

Tags: java, fft, mathcad

In mathcad there are two functions: cfft and icfft. 
I need the same in my java code. It should work for 1d and 2d arrays.

Anyone know any java libraries for it? I tried to use Appache Common Math FastFourierTransformer class, but the length of the data set to be a power of 2.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether [JTransforms](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) suits your needs. It is quite known, very fast implementation.

Comment: I tried it too, but I got a different result for the same data in mathcad and this library.